# Test Managed Package in Professional Edition

Tags: managed-package, professional-edition

I have certified managed package which designed for enterprise/unlimited editions.

I think that some of the package features won't work properly in professional edition but I would like to verify it and then try to enhance those features to work also in professional.

Any recommended options how to do it?
Basically I need test professional org, but I don't think there is a way to configure developer org to have only the professional edition features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably best to sign up for a [trial Professional Edition](https://www.salesforce.com/eu/form/signup/freetrial-sales-pe/) version, install the package, and try it out from there.  It's a 30 day trial which is a good amount of time to test things out.

Note that custom Apex Actions in Flow/Process Builder won't be available in Professional edition.

If you have a Partner Developer org, you should be able to setup an Environment Hub and from there you might be able to create a Professional Edition org.

Comment: Thanks. I just now noticed that in the environment hub there is an option to choose the edition when setting a demo org. Never notice that before