# Managed package Flow actions in profession edition

Tags: visual-workflow, managed-package, invocable-method, professional-edition

I've a managed package that includes several flow actions(Invocable methods). In Enterprise edition, they're available in flow builder, however in professional edition they're not.

I have confirmed in "View Package Components" that the flow actions are installed in the professional edition, they just aren't visible in flow builder.

Is there a setting I'm missing, or is is a limitation in professional edition?

Comment: Is there any existing flow in the PE org? According to the edition comparison chart, PE (Professional edition) has 5 processes and flow https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_au/www/documents/pricing/DS_SalesCloud_EdCompare.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, there are existing flows in the  PE (Professional Edition) org which may explain why new flow from the package is missing.

As per the official [Salesforce Edition Compare](https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_au/www/documents/pricing/DS_SalesCloud_EdCompare.pdf), PE org is allowed 5 Lightning Flow Automation (Flow + Process Builder) per org

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are some important considerations for using Apex in GE/PE:

- GE/PE customers can’t create or modify Apex in your app; they can only run the existing Apex.
- Your Apex code should not depend on features and functionality that exist only in DE, EE, UE, or PXE, or your app will fail to install.
- Make sure to use REST if you plan to expose an Apex method as a Web service. Apex classes that have been exposed as a SOAP Web service can’t be invoked from an external web app in GE/PE.
- Using Apex to make Web service callouts is allowed in GE/PE. For instance, if you’re planning to make a Web service callout to an external Web service, as long as the managed package is authorized, these classes will function in GE/PE.

Documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_packages_apex_ge_pe.htm

Also, you can refer to this may help: [Test Managed Package in Professional Edition](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/398968/test-managed-package-in-professional-edition)